# handler running then close total activity media file continue how to resolve the problem

Tags: android

I am working android application  my problem is  i am using  handlers this handler running audio files  this audiofiles running automatically  every 5 seconds  i am closing total activity   application will be closed but audiofile  also running last position file

how to resolve this problem    please forward some suggestion or some solution its urgent i am new developer in android

Comment: how do you execute the audiofiles??? are u using Mediaplayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this using separate class in audio and update uihandlers in every 5 seconds finish audio file